# Object is possibly 'null' in email validation Angular FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript, mdbootstrap, angular-formbuilder

I get this message when I ng s --aot  `Object is possibly 'null'.`

I've been trying things all morning to fix it, any ideas? The error occurs on the  `<mdb-success *ngIf="email.valid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="mt-2">Email valid</mdb-success>` email.valid, dirty etc objects.

```
 <form class="form-inline md-form form-sm" [formGroup]="validatingForm" (submit)="update(emailInput.value)">
          <input mdbInput mdbValidate type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" placeholder="Enter user's email" aria-label="Search" formControlName="email" #emailInput required />
          <button mdbBtn type="button" color="primary" mdbWavesEffect (click)="update(emailInput.value)">
            <mdb-icon fas icon="search" aria-hidden="true"></mdb-icon>
          </button>
          <mdb-error *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="mt-2">Email invalid</mdb-error>
          <mdb-success *ngIf="email.valid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="mt-2">Email valid</mdb-success>
        </form>
```

ts code:

```
 export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
      validatingForm: FormGroup;
      token: any;
      userDetails: {};
      hasUsers = false;
      emailValue: string;
      constructor(private crudService: CrudService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.validatingForm = new FormGroup({
          email: new FormControl("", Validators.email)
        });
        this.loginAsAdmin();
      }

      get email() {
        return this.validatingForm.get("email");
      }
```

Comment: `*ngIf="email && email.valid && (email.dirty || email.touched)"`

Comment: or you can do like this *ngIf="email?.valid && (email?.dirty || email?.touched)"

Answer (score 1):

*ngIf="email && email.valid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" @ritaj

Answer (score 0):

Only have to *ngIf="email" to solve that error